# Are +X physical damage/armor modifiers already included in the final rating?

Tags: torchlight-2

Let's say I have a claw that has 50 physical damage.  It has a modifier of +10 physical damage.  Does that make the final physical damage rating 60 or does the rating of 50 already include the +10?

Same question for armor.

Answer (score 1):

For weapons, adding a +physical damage socket causes a change in the DPS (which is displayed on the weapon), but will not update the damage dealt per hit.

Comment: Wonder if it will be patched in to update the DPS stats, anyone think it would ever be?

Comment: @Hugabooga Probably not. Maybe you can scrape around for a mod that improves the DPS stat calculations? I'm not sure if that kind of thing is moddable but it's worth checking.